# Why can't I edit a nested model now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `campaign_fax_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb6515200>
```

I have routes defined as follows:

```
map.resources campaigns, :has_many => :faxes
```

The error occurs here:

```
NoMethodError in Faxes#edit

Showing app/views/faxes/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised
```

I use a pretty basic form:

```
 <% form_for [@campaign, @fax] do |f| %>
  2   <%= f.error_messages %>
  3   <p>
  4     Campaign:
  5     <%= link_to @campaign.name, campaign_path(@campaign) %>
  6   </p>
```

When I do a rake routes | grep "campaign_fax*" I get the following:

```
         campaign_faxes GET    /campaigns/:campaign_id/faxes(.:format)               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"faxes"}
       new_campaign_fax GET    /campaigns/:campaign_id/faxes/new(.:format)           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"faxes"}
```

Comment: Do you see `campaign_faxis` anywhere in `rake routes`? Yes, that's `faxis` with an "i".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using rails 2.3.X

Try this in your routes.rb

```
map.resources campaigns do |campaigns|
  campaigns.resources :faxes
end
```

See: The [Nested Routes Section of the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#named-routes)

Comment: I fixed it, but by reading through the guide, can't recall what it was tho.

Answer (score 0):

Showing app/views/faxes/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised

Maybe there is something wrong in the partial. have you check it?

```
map.resources campaigns, :has_many => :faxes **is that correct? I don't think so... maybe is:

map.resources campaign, :has_many => :faxes or

map.resources campaign, :has_many => :faxes

map.resources fax, :has_many => :campaigns
```